# Probability of 7 Card Hand with All Different Ranks?

Tags: probability

Suppose we're dealt a 7 card hand from a standard 52 card deck.  I'm trying to find the probability that all 7 cards are different ranks (that is, no two cards share the same rank).

I know the denominator in this will be 52C6, but I'm not as sure on the numerator.

I was thinking the first card doesn't matter (it's always unique), so something like:

48 * 44 * 40 * 36 * 32 / 52C6

Thoughts?

Thanks,
Mariogs

Comment: The first card is from 52, then subtract 4 each time? Just a thought but i think it would be:  (52*48*44*40*36*32*28) should might be the top? The first card should still be included in the multiplication? Not that sure, but maybe this helped?

Comment: @Link:  Good suggestion. Imagine picking one at a time. The probability the second card is of a new rank is $\frac{48}{51}$. Given this happened, the probability the third card is of a new rank is $\frac{44}{50}$, and so on.

Comment: If you're going to keep track of order in the numerator, you need to do so in the denominator as well, so your denominator needs to be a product, not a combinatorial coefficient. I prefer @FlorianD'Souza's approach, but $\dfrac{52\cdot 48\cdot 44\cdot 40\cdot 36\cdot 32 \cdot 28}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47\cdot 46}$ works, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ${ 52 \choose 7}$ ways of picking a 7 card hand from a deck of 52. I think that is the denominator, not ${52 \choose 6}$. Now, you can pick 7 different ranks ${13 \choose 7} $ ways, and each could be 1 of 4 possible suits. Therefore, the probability should be $\frac{{13 \choose 7} \times 4^7}{{52 \choose 7}} = 0.21$